# most recent (max) date for every id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
a = id  
b = date  
c = NewestDate
```

For every a, I have b c

**How can I get the newest date for every set of id's** (MY 'a' column)? they don't all have the same end date. So I do need a max for all of them.

The data is in myTable,
so far i tried:

```
select * 
into #myTable 
from myTable

select 
t.a
,t.b
,t.c 
,(select max(b) from myTable) as c
from myTable t 
left join #myTable t1
on t.a = t1.a and t.b = t1.b
order by a, b
```

The problem with the above code is that in 'c' it is placed the max date of them all, which is not what I actually want.

**EDIT:** the problem is now solved with the answer given by Dmitry Poliakov (thanks). Used:

```
SELECT a,
    b,
    max(b) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS c
FROM myTable
ORDER BY a,b
```

Comment: Window functions are your friends.

Comment: what do you mean by that? sorry not that experienced with this

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: `OVER/PARTITION BY/ORDER BY` that's all you need

Comment: i never used over/partition before. How can i use that with i already have? Sorry but quite new to this part of sql

Comment: Just try, put some effort to do it, you will learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can select maximum date for each group of ids as

```
SELECT a,
    b,
    max(b) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS c
FROM myTable
ORDER BY a,b
```

**EDIT:** one of possible solutions for the second(edited) part of question is

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT a,
        b,
        max(b) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS c,
        d
    FROM myTable
)
SELECT t1.a,
    t1.b,
    t1.c,
    t1.d,
    t2.d AS e
FROM cte t1
JOIN cte t2 ON t1.a=t2.a AND t1.c=t2.b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @updates TABLE (a int,b date,c date)
INSERT INTO @updates VALUES 
  (1,GETDATE(),GETDATE()+10), 
  (2,GETDATE()+11,GETDATE()+13),
  (2,GETDATE()+11,GETDATE()+14),
  (3,GETDATE()+11,GETDATE()+13),
  (1,GETDATE()+11,GETDATE()+13);

WITH
  cte AS
  (
    SELECT  a, max(c) latest
    FROM  @updates
    GROUP BY a
  )

SELECT  *  
FROM  cte INNER JOIN @updates as d ON cte.a=d.a AND cte.latest = d.c
```

Builds a table to select the records with the newest updates and then joins this new table with your original table to extract all the fields in matching rows