# current value of a column for every id according to the newest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

This question is taking my previous problem further: ([most recent (max) date for every id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467553/most-recent-max-date-for-every-id))
Suppose i have a table 
which has

```
    a = id
    b = date
    c = NewestDate 
    d = someValues -- ex 0.3
    e = currentValue --this is what i need to create
```

For every a (id) i have b,c,d 
I want to create 'e' with for every 'a' checks the date in 'c' then in 'e' it's being inserted the corresponding value from 'd'.
the column c was created like this:

```
SELECT  a,
        b,
        max(b) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS c
    FROM myTable
    ORDER BY a,b
```

example:

```
a        b           c           d        e
1    2009.02.15   2015.03.20    0.432   0.122 --e taken from the row below
1    2015.03.20   2015.03.20    0.122   0.122 --the value of e
1    2014.04.02   2015.03.20    0.98    0.122 --e taken from the row above 
2    2010.04.12   2014.07.01    0.467   0.578  
2    2014.07.01   2014.07.01    0.578   0.578
.
.
```

**Anyone has a solution for this?**

tried like this:

```
select * 
into #myTable
from myTable

select 
t1.a,
t1.b,
t1.c,
t1.d,
t.d as e
from #myTable t
left join myTable t1 on t.c = t1.b and t.a = t1.a
order by a, b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just use conditional aggregation with a window function:

```
SELECT t.*,
       MAX(CASE WHEN b = c THEN d END) OVER (PARTITION BY a) as d
FROM (SELECT a, b, max(b) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS c
      FROM myTable
     ) t
ORDER BY a, b
```